# how to speed up 'ng' and 'npm' commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, angular, npm

I'm working on a Windows 7 with SSD HD, i7 and 16GB RAM.. a good machine to develop i think. I'm starting to work with angular and so i started to use npm and ng to develop some example apps. I put node.js in path variable environment.

My problem is that every command like 'ng generate ...', 'ng serve' is very slow to start. It seems to wait or look for something. I monitored CPU and discs, but they are no under stress.

Is there any way to improve performance of npm and ng?

Comment: its based on your internet speed. Have a look at the size of **node_modules**

Comment: An alternative to `npm` is [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/), which has improved caching for faster package installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your anti-virus settings.  NPM and Node use a ton of small js files and if your antivirus has to scan every file with each command, you're gonna experience slowdown.

So, first try temporarily turning off the active protection on your anti-virus first and seeing if that makes a difference. If it does, then you may have to get your settings adjusted so that your project files aren't part of the real time protection.

Answer (score -1):

It totally depends on your internet speed and size of node modules. It has nothing to do with your system configuration.

Thanks